# Entity Framework Distinct Values

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

While developing an application I realized by queries was really show for getting only 200 values from a database. It showed out it was my distinct that slowed it down. As far as I can read Distinct takes all elements from database and do a distinct afterwards and thats the reason. Tried with group by, but also slow performance. What is the right way to do this ?

```
model.AlarmLevelDistinct = myDbCtx.StatusView.GroupBy(p => p.AlarmLevel).First().Select(p => p.AlarmLevel).ToList();

model.ParametersDistinct = myDbCtx.StatusView.Select(p => p.Parameter).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Distinct will always create a slower query. You can try sorting out distinct entries in memory instead of on the DB side

Comment: @StevenAckley distinct on DB-side is faster than distinct in memory. EF generates the statement. since we don't know any data from Thomas, we don't know why it's that slow. He maybe would post the log EF writes? they contain the queries :)

Comment: The answer to _"Why is this query slow?"_ is always _"Profile it"_. From there you can do more research, for example adding an index or two might help.

Comment: The `AlarmLevelDistinct` statement isn't correct. It only takes the first group. Also, it matters whether the statements are translated into SQL, which depends on what `statusView` actually is.

Comment: Thanks guys, changed the code sample. I have table with 500000 elements, and lets say with 4 different values. I want those 4 values disitinct without pulling 500000 values from the database into memory to do a distinct. And correct me if I am wrong. As far as I know Distinct will pull all the elements from the DB into memory and then do a distinct. This is not optimal if it is correct. So how do you in EF do a "select name from databasename group by name" without pulling all values into the application?

Comment: Use that as template https://forums.asp.net/t/1865932.aspx?How+to+group+by+in+entity+framework+

Comment: Hi Steven. Which answer you refer too? I am starting to belive the last anser is the right answer. Skipping EF for group by's and just using plain SQL for those queries.

Comment: I have just mad a sample of the same code but with ExecuteSql instaed. EF Destinct 2.6 seconds ExecuteSql 800 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var model.AlarmLevelDistinct = myDbCtx.StatusView.GroupBy(c=> c.AlarmLevel).Select(x=> x.Key);
```